# How can I tell if my numlock etc. buttons are active if I don't have a light?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, capslock, numlock

My home laptop doesn't have any lights or indicators to show that I've got numlock, caps lock or scroll lock on. The only indication I get is when a program tells me I got caps lock on when entering a password, and that's just for caps lock. It's possible I missed this indicator somewhere, but there is no indicator near the button and no indicator above the keyboard.

I use Windows 7, with an Acer Aspire 2528 (I think, haven't checked the serial number recently, but it's a few years old by now, from 2010). I'm looking for preferably a built-in message from  Windows which will tell me if I got numlock or caps lock enabled.

Comment: I can't believe such question exists.

Comment: @Joset Why, exactly? I doubt my laptop model is the only one without indicator lights.

Comment: because the fastest way to know is by following what @gladiator2345 said

Comment: 1) @gladiator2345 doesn't account for shift-lock; 2) You don't always have a text field to enter keys into, while the effect can differ based on the state of these lock buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest method:
Type one character, then press 4 on num pad:

- If a character is typed in the field, then num lock is on.
- If cursor moves to left then num lock is off.

When num lock is off 4 works as left arrow key.

Comment: as addition i think a link to the official Microsoftpage on the topic startup behaviour would be helpful too http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/want-to-set-num-lock-to-be-on-and-active-at/7b48ae6f-fa9c-4bc2-8359-81e0c5e5d6a2

Answer (score 6):

For Windows 10 with no num lock indicator light, you can go to SETTINGS, EASE OF ACCESS, KEYBOARD, USE OF TOGGLE KEYS, TURN ON SOUND so that a sound will alert you when caps lot, num lock, etc is on. 
I didn't realize this until after I brought my laptop home. I never thought to ask at Best Buy either. HP you did a disservice when you don't have this as a simple basic on the laptop for this model.

Answer (score 2):

Use the native Windoze "on screen keyboard": open CMD and type osk
or just type "osk" on Cortana search.
There is an options key on the on screen keyboard that you have to open and click "turn on numeric pad".
Voila ! You will have all indicators you need.

But I agree, it's rather intrusive... I'd rather have a small all always running to tell me that and I could just glance at it.
My problem is that my external keyboard HAS the lights, but I'm on a Macbook and thanks Apple, the num lock doesn't lite up; my last resource is the "osk"

Answer (score 1):

download Keyboard indicator for your tray from

http://roidayan.com/2015/06/here-is-keyboard-indicator-v1-6/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Office installed, start Excel and check the status bar, it lists all the lock keys if they are on.
Right click on the status bar to check which keys are indicated, you can check and uncheck them.

Answer (score 0):

On LINUX, You can try getting info with [xset](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html):

```
xset q | grep Caps
```

Result:

```
00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
```

For more options, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207766/20661